# Why cloning of email thread in Case didn't work with Lightning

Tags: trigger, lightning, case, salesforce-classic, emailmessage

Can someone help us. We are wondering why cloning of email thread from one case to another didn't work in Lightning. But it works well with Salesforce classic.

In lightning it give us an error.

**Operation is not allowed.**[image]

Please see our trigger:

```
 `for(EmailMessage emailRec :emailRecList){
        for(Case caseRec : caseRecList){
            if(emailRec.Extract__c){
                EmailMessage emailRecNew = new EmailMessage();
                emailRecNew.ParentId = emailRec.Transfer_to_Case__c;
                caseRec.Attach_Email__c = TRUE;
                emailRectListNew.add(emailRecNew);
            }
        }
    } `
```

Thanks for your help.

lone

Comment: Have you checked the logs to see more information about the error you are getting?

Comment: Hi @DanKowalski we checked the logs and try to do debug on our trigger and it is all good.

Comment: When does your trigger trigger fire? Meaning is it before insert/update or after insert/update?

Comment: Hi @DanKowalski trigger fires after update.